# How to get fast at visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've seen a lot of developers who move across VS almost quicker than you can see. A lot of it seems to be short cut keys. I'm a terrible hunt and find it in the menu. Is there a tried and test way of getting your speed up to dome of the VS masters? Is it just memorizing all those short cut keys. Maybe removing the menus so that you can ONLY use the shortcuts? How have others done it? Are there other techniques?

EDIT

I've seen a lot of the key-binding and key code lists. But its actually going about putting in practice so that its second nature.

Comment: This is something I wouldn't mind know myself - don't know how long it taken me to force myself to us CTR+F

Comment: Cutting the mouse umbilical cord is an obvious approach.  That slows you down for a week or two only, bliss after that.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't my forte but... print out a spreadsheet, if you will, of all the shortcuts you think you might like to use.

Plaster it to your desk. *Whenever* you would like to reach for a menu, force yourself to go over this spreadsheet.

Slower at first, faster in the end.

(See the link below for a list of spreadsheets from Microsoft, though you may want to reformat the data there.)

Good luck sir.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13189